# Include Craft JS object

Tags: plugin-development, javascript

In the [controller documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers) for plugins, there's a section that talks about routing to specific actions using a `Craft` object like this:

```
var url = Craft.getActionUrl('cocktailRecipes/ingredients/saveIngredient', { id: 10 });
```

I think this object is the one in `/craft/app/resources/js/craft.js`, but I can't figure out how to make it available. I tried including it via `includeJsResource`, but this doesn't appear to be working

```
{% includeJsResource "resources/js/craft.js" %}
```

What do I need to include to be able to use this object in my JavaScript (it is not a load ordering issue, the URL generated by includeJsResource goes to the 404 page)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Craft` global variable is available to any Javascript running in the backend/Control Panel, without including anything.

It's not possible to include, reference or use the global for any code running in the frontend.

---

EDIT:

To provide access to a controller action for frontend Javascript, I'd recommend setting up a [site route](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#registerSiteRoutes) in your plugin's main class. The following will route the URL `http://yourbaseurl/myplugin/foobar/add` to `ExampleController`:

```
public function registerSiteRoutes()
{
    return array(
        'myplugin/foobar/add' => array('action' => 'myPlugin/example/add'),
    );
}
```

As for the ExampleController, be sure to set the `$allowAnonymous` class variable to `true`. This allows visitors that aren't logged in to Craft access (beware that this will make *all* your controller´s actions accessible without login):

```
class MyPlugin_ExampleController extends BaseController
{
   protected $allowAnonymous = true;
   public function actionAdd()
   {
       // Your code here           
   }
}
```

Comment: In that case, how do I reach the business logic from the frontend? I have a plugin with a BasicController that has a method actionAdd, and I've tried navigating to /actions/basicController/add, and I get a 404

Comment: The cleanest way would probably be to add a [site route](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#registerSiteRoutes) and point that to your controller, e.g. ```'myplugin/add' => array( 'action' => 'myPlugin/basic/add' )```, then call ```http://yourbaseurl.com/myplugin/add``` with $.ajax() in your frontend JS.

Comment: I'm assuming that `registerSiteRoutes` goes in the BasicPlugin.php file? Because I've added it, and I'm still getting 404s. EDIT: I decided to go into the PluginService and use `print_r` to see all the Plugins that are loaded, and my plugin, as well as another that I downloaded and dumped into the `plugins` directory, do not appear in that list

Comment: You might need to allow anonymous (i.e. not logged in) access to your controller. This is done by setting the ```$allowAnonymous``` variable of your controller class to ```true```: ```protected $allowAnonymous = true;```

Comment: I can confirm that `$allowAnonymous` is protected, true, and not misspelled

Comment: Well, then you might need to post your base plugin class and controller. Difficult to say where this goes wrong for you.

Comment: Regarding the edit to your comment above – apologize if this is a silly question, but you have _installed_ your plugin, right? Dumping plugins into the plugins directory wont automatically install/activate plugins.

Comment: Um, I have not. I just started reading the Plugin docs and coding away in the plugins directory. Craft was already setup so I was unaware that there was an installation step for the plugin. I have admin credentials though, where do I install the plugin from?

Comment: Visit the Settings area in the CP by clicking the upper right cogwheel icon – you'll find a link to the plugin management area from there.

Comment: Excellent! It works. You're a saint, thanks x 1000, I mean it

Comment: Awesome – my pleasure!

Comment: _Edited the answer to provide info on how to set up a site route pointing to a controller action._

Comment: You're a machine, @MatsMikkelRummelhoff.

Comment: I wish, @BradBell :)